# Can't fetch the name of different suppliers from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python using post requests to fetch the name of different suppliers from a webpage but unfortunately I'm getting this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` whereas it occured to me that I did things in the right way.

[websitelink](https://www.gebiz.gov.sg/ptn/supplier/directory/index.xhtml)

To populate the content, it is required to click on the search button just the way it is seen in the image.

[image]

I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.gebiz.gov.sg/ptn/supplier/directory/index.xhtml"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")

payload = {
    'contentForm': 'contentForm',
    'contentForm:j_idt225_listButton2_HIDDEN-INPUT': '',
    'contentForm:j_idt161_inputText': '',
    'contentForm:j_idt164_SEARCH': '',
    'contentForm:j_idt167_selectManyMenu_SEARCH-INPUT': '',
    'contentForm:j_idt167_selectManyMenu-HIDDEN-INPUT': '',
    'contentForm:j_idt167_selectManyMenu-HIDDEN-ACTION-INPUT': '',
    'contentForm:search': 'Search',
    'contentForm:j_idt185_select': 'SUPPLIER_NAME',
    'javax.faces.ViewState': soup.select_one('[id="javax.faces.ViewState"]')['value']
}

res = requests.post(url,data=payload,headers={
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'
    })
sauce = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
item = sauce.select_one(".form2_ROW").text
print(item)
```

> Only this portion will do as well: ***`8121 results found.`***

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\general_demo.py", line 27, in <module>
    item = sauce.select_one(".form2_ROW").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback including which line of code caused that error.

Comment: Where did you print the value of the variable -- the one for which you take the `.text` attribute?  The message is telling you clearly that the variable is `None`.

Comment: what are typing into those search fields?

Comment: Typing nothing in those search fields. Just clicked the search button. By default the two search fields are already selected by `All` @chitown88.

Comment: Check out the edit @GiraffeMan91.

Comment: Ok. And where did you locate the url to make the post? I’m not finding/seeing that in the dev tools.

Comment: I found that url using dev tools. Try reloading the page when you have already opened dev tools and selected `All` tab in network.

Comment: As the message is clearly telling me that the vaiable is `None`, I created this post to seek help in order to get a valid response. Does this make sense @Prune?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find a way to get the cookie. The following currently works for me across multiple requests.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.gebiz.gov.sg/ptn/supplier/directory/index.xhtml"

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Referer' : 'https://www.gebiz.gov.sg/ptn/supplier/directory/index.xhtml',
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0',
    'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
    'Cookie' : '__cfduid=d3fe47b7a0a7f3ef307c266817231b5881555951761; wlsessionid=pFpF87sa9OCxQhUzwQ3lXcKzo04j45DP3lIVYylizkFMuIbGi6Ka!1395223647; BIGipServerPTN2_PRD_Pool=52519072.47873.0000'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(url, headers= headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {
        'contentForm': 'contentForm',
        'contentForm:search': 'Search',
        'contentForm:j_idt185_select': 'SUPPLIER_NAME',
        'javax.faces.ViewState': soup.select_one('[id="javax.faces.ViewState"]')['value']
    }
    res = s.post(url,data=payload,headers= headers)
    sauce = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    item = sauce.select_one(".formOutputText_HIDDEN-LABEL.outputText_TITLE-BLACK").text
    print(item)
```

Comment: I should have thought about that cookie thing. Getting lazy really.